# Get previous value on Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, binding

I am trying to get the previous value of textbox binding. Binding is like:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding UserName}" />
```

There is string property in viewModel and i am following strict MVVM approach.
Is there any available property or event or any workaround to get the previous textbox value in xaml?

Thanks

EDIT : I thought that i can write interaction trigger to the got keyboard focus event and i can bind the current value as previous value to some other property. With that way i can have the previous value right?

Comment: maybe you have a xy problem. What do you want to achieve? Somekind of Undo? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: When and where exactly you want this previous value ?

Comment: @AnjumSKhan I want to get the previous value when textbox's text property changed. Actually if i can get the previous value to another property then it could be great.

Comment: You already have the previous value inside you property setter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using binding your property `UserName` uses an event to tell the text box for change. This event might be of `INotifyPropertyChanged` class or `DependencyProperty`, both of which have events you can listen to.

If you need more info post the code for context class

Comment: Is there any available solution on xaml side? like <Textblock PreviousValue="something"/>

Comment: Textbox is a dependency object you are able to listen for it's TextProperty changed event in code behind. Not so MVVM though. Strict MVVM says you should work with UserName property not the text box. If you want use the code behind

Comment: @stackerflow The only way to do it on XAML is to extend the original `TextBox` class, turning it into a custom control. Then you add dependency properties and all your undo logic codes in there, then use it like other controls. This way you don't pollute your MVVM implementation.

Comment: @stackerflow flow maybe you can share more about what you really want to achieve.

Comment: @stackerflow The most MVVM way to do it though, is to track this at ViewModel (maybe a List<>), then bind `UserName` two-way. This way you can change the value of `UserName` at ViewModel, and View will automatically pick up the changes.

Comment: @Jai your idea is enlightening. I am going to try it thanks. I can change my implementation on viewModel respect to this way.